# In @react-navigation's Tab.Navigator, I aim to lock the final screen while allowing the rest to scroll

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation

In @react-navigation's Tab.Navigator, I aim to lock the final screen while allowing the rest to scroll.
The rendering of code

I am grateful for the assistance provided by all of you.

```
{/* <Tab.Navigator
screenOptions={{
tabBarItemStyle: { width: 80, height: 30 }
}}
>
{TagTabNavigationData.map((item, index) => (
<Tab.Screen
key={item.id}
name={item.title}
component={item.component}
options={{
// tabBarInactiveTintColor: item.inactiveTintColor,
title: item.title,

tabBarStyle: styles.Item,
tabBarScrollEnabled: index === index + 1 ? true : false
}}
 />
))}
<Tab.Screen
name="23"
component={Demo1}
options={{
tabBarIconStyle: styles.Item,
lazy: true,
tabBarShowLabel: false,
abBarShowIcon: false
}}
/>
</Tab.Navigator> */}
```

The first time published, also do not know what happened, has been reporting mistakes, I am so tired. What I actually wanted to do was: the map component could slide, and then I added a non-display component to make it non-sliding, but I tried a lot of methods still failed

Finally, thank you very much, I hope you are healthy, all the best, happy every day